# Cannot access Apache website within VMware Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, networking, apache-http-server, vmware, owncloud

I installed a Bitnami image of ownCloud in my Windows 10 host. The image itself is a Debian 8 distro, which I run in VMware player with bridged mode networking.

Everything works fine in my LAN; the VM has its own IP (listens at port 8090), and I can casually login to ownCloud from any of my devices in my house.

Unfortunately, when I try to access the server from the Internet I get a **timeout error** when I am loading the webpage. (The port 8090 is forwarded from my GoogleHub router to the external 19800.)

Relevant info:

1. The VM can access the Internet and download content (wget, etc., work)
2. I disabled temporarily the firewall of the VM but it did not resolve my problem
3. I restarted the router, the host and the VM
4. The address of the remote PC is whitelisted in ownCloud (kinda irrelevant, because I do not even reach to the ownCloud banner page that would inform me that I am not authorized to access it)
5. Port 8090 is opened in Windows Firewall (TCP inbound)
6. http://canyouseeme.org/ reports that port 19800 is open to the Internet

Anything else I can try?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree with bummi's comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."

Answer (score -1):

Ah nice reproducible networking.

Suddenly it started working without me changing anything.